# How to make q-input components smaller in quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework

The q-input components are fairly large in size with a fair amount of padding and a decently large font. I don't see anything in the documentation to make them smaller. I'm specifically looking to decrease the height of these components, but any strategy to be able to change the size would be suitable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use dense mode to make all quasar components use less space (this also makes components smaller). For a example with q-input look at this anchor [at the quasar documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#Outlined).

Comment: Thank you! I hunted around that page, but there's so much there I missed that parameter.

Comment: how about smaller than dense? is it possible

Answer (score 1):

To make it smaller than dense.

Add the class "input-box" to the q-input component and then:

```
<style scoped>
:deep(.input-box .q-field__control),
:deep(.input-box .q-field__marginal) {
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```